# Returning the number of times a number appears in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So I'm doing a bunch of exercises, one of them asks me to write a method that is passed an array with each slot type int. This method should return the number of times 99 occurs in the array. Here's what I came up with on the fly:

```
public static int countNum(int[]x)
{
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= x.length;i++);
{
 if (x[i] == 99)
   count++;
}
return count;
}
```

All in all, I just need to write the method. Am I on the right track?

Comment: There is a bug, but you're on the right track. You should really test your own code before asking us. Create a main method, create an array with hard-coded elements, call your method, and see if it works fine and returns the expected number.

Comment: Not too bad a track to be on...

Comment: There are actually two bugs.  Both of them are just typos, where there's an extra character that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Hint: the mistake that's causing the compilation error is actually two lines above where the error is being reported.

Comment: `return (int) Arrays.stream(x).filter(t -> t == 99).count();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two mistakes.
First: `i < x.length;` it should be like that or `i <= x.length - 1;` like that or you will get out of your array.
Second:

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= x.length;i++)**;**
  {
      if (x[i] == 99)
      count++;
  }
```

You don't need **;** or the next code will be out of *for*.

Comment: Ah darn it, silly little mistakes of mine hahaha. Thank you!

Comment: @BugScramble you can like and take my question)

Answer (score 0):

1. array.length returns length of an array and you don't want to iterate from 0 to `length`, but from 0 to `length - 1`. 
   Why? For example if an array is [1, 5] then:
   `array.length == 2`, `array[0] == 1`, `array[1] == 5` but `array[2]` throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (because it tries to reach an element which is not in the array)
2. Remove the semicolon after the for statement:

   `for (int i = 0; i <= x.length;i++);`

   (a for loop executes statements which comes directly after it, and ";" ends a statement. The for(...) followed by ";" means that you have a loop which does nothing x.length times)